# Installing rpm module for (non-system) Python

Tags: python, rpm

I need to support some software that is using an old Python version (2.4).  So I have downloaded and compiled Python 2.4 and installed it in a virtualenv.  So far, all OK and normal procedure.

But the software is trying to import an `rpm` module.  And I cannot find a source for that module (it is not part of the standard Python library, afaict).

Typically, once the virtualenv is enabled (`source env/bin/activate`) I can install required software using `easy_install`.  But `easy_install rpm` is failing to find anything.  There is a [pyrpm](https://github.com/mjvm/pyrpm) module, but it is not the same thing (it installs a module called "pyrpm").  And google searches are useless, as they all link to articles on how to build rpms...

If I were using the system python (on Ubuntu) I could install the `python-rpm` package.  But that is for Python 2.7.  How do I install the equivalent for Python 2.4?

[My impression is that the rpm libraries, used by many Linux systems, include a Python library, which is packaged as python-dev by the distro.  But I can't see how to access that for an arbitrary python version.]

**I AM NOT LOOKING FOR AN RPM THAT CONTAINS PYTHON 2.4.  I AM LOOKING FOR A MODULE NAMED rpm THAT IS USED BY SOFTWARE WRITTEN FOR PYTHON 2.4.**

Comment: how about compiling from source instead of installing rpm ?

Comment: sure, but where is the source?  and by "installing rpm" what do you mean?  have you misunderstood the q?  easy_install *is* installing from the source, basically.

Comment: Python 2.4.6 : http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.4.6/

Comment: so you didn't read the first paragraph of my question?  i have installed that.  it does not include an rpm module.

Comment: i misread the question. here is the RPM source ( http://www.rpm.org/wiki/Download ), still finding which version is correct.

Comment: Blind guess: Python 2.4.6 released on 2008-12-19 , Nearest RPM version was released on 2009-2-6, of version 4.6.0

Comment: On what OS is this for? I see two packages in Red Hat Linux that contain rpm.py.

Comment: if you look at the [pyrpm pypi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyrpm/0.3) there is an example of from pyrpm.rpm import RPM, perhaps before 2.6 support was enabled it was used just via import rpm? It might be worth investigating old releases.

Comment: @ZaSter - the problem is that linux packages are for the system python.  they don't directly install for a different python version.

Comment: @andrewcooke Is it correct, that the software fails to run with python 2.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's no simple way to do this; the python library is part of the system rpm package and interfaces to C code, so is closely tied to the rpm package installed on your machine.

instead, it's much simpler to install an old OS in a VM (eg CentOS 5) that uses Python 2.4.  then everything is consistent and works.

Answer (score 1):

It's right there, in the python-rpm RPM package:

http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=python-rpm

You will probably want to download the package contents, extract them, and then use

```
python setup.py install
```

From your active environment.

Of course, as it's pre compiled, you might have trouble getting the C extension to run.

I'm not familiar enough with RPM's to know whether you can get the source from there.

---

No guarantees the package will work with your python version though.

Comment: @andrewcooke You could take the email addresses from the change log, and ask the maintainers for directions. There probably is a source under version control somewhere!

Answer (score 1):

the sources for the rpm module can be found here: http://www.rpm.org/wiki/Download

After you download the wanted version read and follow the INSTALL instructions in order to compile it on your target OS. Afterwards make sure you add the correct path to the 'site-packages' folder the installation chose into your PYTHONPATH environment variable.

To test start your python interpreter and run 'import rpm'

HTH,

Ran

Comment: that installs *everything* - you get the rpm package and the python wrapper.  it does not give you a wrapper around the already existing system rpm package.